# Filter dates saved as String in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, date, core-data

For learning purpose I have created a `CoreData` project and as expected for someone just started learning swift, I have been stuck quite often.

So far I have managed to understand how to save data to `CoreDate` and to display it in a table. But now I want to go a step further.

I have an Entity from few `String (startDate, endDate,...)` What is the right approach to retrieve the number of days per year, set be the intervals from start and end dates? for example if:

```
dateInterval1 = from Dec 30, 2014 to Jan 01, 2015 
dateInterval2 = from May 01, 2015 to May 10, 2015 
dateInterval3 = from Dec 30, 2015 to Jan 01, 2016
```

I want to count how many days from the intervals above are in 2015 (1+10+2)

I'm sorry for the question without any line of code. I'm playing in the playGround with `Array [NSDate]` converted to string, which become a bit messy, so decide the will be confusing to posted hear. Any help for the right approach will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to count how many days from the intervals above are in 2015 (1+10+2)

You can't do this directly with Core Data. It doesn't support date math. It **especially** does not support date math when the dates are stored as *strings*.

The best you could do with the Core Data entity you describe is:

1. Fetch all instances where either the start date or the end date is a string ending with "2015".
2. For each fetched object, convert the string to an `NSDate` (in code, not automatically by Core Data) and then do your date math.

This would work but would be extremely inefficient. Step 1 involves comparing two strings for every object in your persistent store. Step 2 involves parsing two date strings for every fetched object. It's a lousy approach but it's the only one your entity allows for.

One approach that would be a lot better is:

1. Change your entity to store dates as "Date" data instead of as strings.
2. Fetch objects with dates in 2015. For the start date you'd do something like:

   ```
   let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
   let startOf2015 = calendar.dateWithEra(1, year: 2015, month: 1, day: 1, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)
   ```

   (Note that you may need to change the `timeZone` value on the calendar).

   Then you would make your Core Data predicate include something like `startDate > %@`, with `startOf2015` as the argument matching that `%@`.
3. Calculate how many days from `startOf2015` to the `startDate` on each object:

   ```
   let startDate = myObject.startDate

   let components = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: startOf2015!, toDate: startDate, options: NSCalendarOptions.allZeros)
   ```

   Now `components.day` is how many days from one date to the other.

The process for `endDate` is basically the same.